# Program type already present - Tipsi-Stripe

Tags: android, stripe-payments, react-native

I am trying to implement tipsi-stripe into my react-native app for android.

Upon adding a second maven repository for stripe (jitpack):

```
allprojects {
  repositories {
    maven {
      // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
      url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
    }
    //Second maven was added per linking instructions on tipsi-stripe docs. 
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io"}
    jcenter()
    google()
  }
}
```

I receive the following error:

```
D8: Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcce
```

Based on previous posts with similar issues, it seems this has to do with a versioning difference with firebase (I'm assuming jitpack uses these dependencies based on the solutions proposed).

I watched the build and the following firebase libraries are downloaded:

[image]

In an attempt to resovle the issue by providing the correct versions I added the corresponding firebase implementations:

**android/app/build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"


def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false


def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.testforce.android"
        multiDexEnabled true
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    implementation project(':tipsi-stripe')
    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    implementation(project(':react-native-maps')){
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-maps'
  }
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:12.0.1'
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:12.0.1'
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.3'
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"
    api project(':libs:SalesforceReact') // From node_modules
}


task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
  from configurations.compile
  into 'libs'
}
```

The app now builds successfully, but upon launch on the emulator the app stops working and closes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade play-services-maps:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
```